# From PFX and CRT to Pub and Private key in DER format

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl

So I read that this command

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -outform der -in 1.crt  > 1_pubkey.der
```

Should give me the public key in der format, but it says than the > is an unknown parameter.. Then I tried without > and with -out instead.. But it gave me something mixed of base64 and binary encoded.

How can I make sure this is only binary?

And I'm not sure how to get a private key in DER either.. Can anyone help me with the commands?

I have the following files:

.pfx .crt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Public Key

Use `openssl x509 -pubkey` to extract the public key (both the public key and certificate in PEM), then pipe that into `openssl rsa -pubin -outform DER` to convert the public key to DER.  The `-out <filename>` option saves you having to redirect the output.

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -in 1.crt | openssl rsa -pubin -outform DER -out 1_pubkey.der
```

#### Private Key

Simply extract the private key from the `.pfx` first with `openssl pkcs12 -in 1.pfx -nocerts` and pipe that into `openssl rsa -outform DER` to convert it:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in 1.pfx -nocerts | openssl rsa -outform DER -out 1_privkey.der
```

The above will ask for the `.pfx` private key initially then ask you for a new pass phrase for the PEM (twice) before asking you again for the PEM pass phrase when it converts from PEM to DER.

Comment: I use Windows and cPanel on Linux. What I have are .crt and .key files. I need a .pub file. Is there a document somewhere that explains all these formats and how to interconvert?

Comment: @DavidSpector - why don't you post a new question? :-)

Comment: I've kind of figured it out: there are three types of credentials on cPanel: first, the .CRT and .KEY files for each domain/user on the account; these can be downloaded to be used for local/development HTTPS websites. Second, a .PPK file for FTP and remote shell programs, which has a passphrase; not sure how these are created, but can't be hard since I've already done it. Third, .PUB and .KEY files for sFTP and ssh2/scp access using PHP scripts, which are allocated in cPanel for domain/user or in WHM for root access. None of these files have to be interconverted, I'm guessing.